# Qual a divisão silábica forma das palavras "própria", "polícia", "óleo" e "ministério"?

Tags: divisão-silábica, separação-silábica

Procurando pela *web* encontrei duas formas de divisão silábica para as palavras  *própria*, *polícia* e *ministério*:

**pró-pri-a** ou **pró-pria**;
**po-lí-ci-a** ou **po-lí-cia**;
**ó-le-o** ou **ó-leo**;
**mi-nis-té-ri-o** ou **mi-nis-té-rio**.

Qual a forma correta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regras são: *Não se separam ditongo e tritongo* e *Separam-se os hiatos*.

De acordo com o [Vocabulário Ortográfico Português](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/vop.html), o correto é:

- pró·pri·o;
- po·lí·ci·a;
- ó·le·o; e
- mi·nis·té·ri·o

Acontece que, no Brasil, os ditongos crescentes finais: *-ea, -eo, -ia, -ie, -io, -oa, -ua, -ue, -uo*, seguidos ou não de *s*, são considerados pela [Nomenclatura Gramatical Brasileira](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=ngbras) como ditongos; outros gramáticos, porém, consideram-nos como hiatos. Ou seja, no Brasil não há um consenso, portanto tanto faz utilizar:

- pró·pri·o **ou** pró·prio;
- po·lí·ci·a **ou** po·lí·cia;
- ó·le·o **ou** ó·leo; e
- mi·nis·té·ri·o **ou** mi·nis·té·rio

Answer (score 3):

Segundo o site https://www.separaremsilabas.com/ tem diferenças entre Brasil e o resto dos países falantes de Português

Própria:

- pró-pria (no Brasil)
- pró-pri-a (no Portugal e restante CPLP)

> Quantas sílabas tem própria? 2 sílabas (no Brasil), ou 3 sílabas (no
>   Portugal e restante CPLP). No Brasil é uma palavra grave ou também
>   chamado paroxítona (acento tônico na penúltima sílaba). No Portugal e
>   restante CPLP, é uma palavra proparoxítona (acento tónico na
>   antepenúltima sílaba). ■ Hiato i-a. Veja mais exemplos do palavras con
>   'ia'. ■ Exceções: Palavras terminadas em hiato 'i-a'; com a sílaba
>   anterior acentuada são indivisíveis. Exemplos: fa-mí-lia, pá-tria.
>   Veja mais exemplos do palavras con 'ia' ■ O Acordo Ortográfico Da
>   Língua Portuguesa (1990), Base VII, 2º-C, diz: Além dos ditongos orais
>   propriamente ditos, os quais são todos decrescentes, admite-se, como é
>   sabido, a existência de ditongos crescentes. Podem considerar-se no
>   número deles as sequências vocálicas pós-tónicas/pós-tônicas, tais as
>   que se representam graficamente por ea, eo, ia, ie, io, oa, ua, ue,
>   uo: áurea, áureo, calúnia, espécie, exímio, mágoa, míngua,
>   ténue/tênue, tríduo. ■ [i + vogal] Se a letra 'i' não acentuada for
>   seguida por outra vogal não acentuada este encontro vocálico pode ser
>   pronunciado de duas maneiras distintas:
>     1. Como ditongo crescente 'ia', 'ie', 'ii', 'io', 'iu', com a pronúncia das duas vogais em uma mesma sílaba e realização de 'i' como
>   semivogal. Exemplos: fé-rias, a-gên-cia.
>     2. Como hiato 'i-a', 'i-e', 'i-i', 'i-o', 'i-u', com a separação das duas vogais em duas sílabas distintas e a representação de 'i' como
>   vogal. Exemplos: fé-ri-as, a-gên-ci-a. A escolha da variante mais
>   adequada para estes casos é facultativa e poderá ser motivada por
>   razões de ordem técnica ou estética. ■ De acordo com o site
>   Wiktionary: A categoria de palavras proparoxítonas aparentes foi
>   criada no wikcionário para resolver o problema das palavras que são
>   classificadas segundo seu acento tônico de uma maneira no Brasil e de
>   outra em Portugal, especificamente aquelas que são acentuadas por
>   terminarem em um ditongo crescente (-ea, -eo, -ia, -ie, -io, -ua, -ue
>   e -uo), que são classificadas como paroxítonas terminadas em ditongo
>   no Brasil, mas como proparoxítonas no restante da CPLP. Exemplo:
>   Palavras como sério, bário, tília, são consideradas como dissílabas no
>   Brasil (suas divisões silábicas são respectivamente sé-rio, bá-rio,
>   tí-lia) mas são vistas como trissílabas em Portugal, onde suas
>   divisões silábicas seriam sé-ri-o, bá-ri-o, tí-li-a. ■ Possível
>   dígrafo de consoantes formados por 'pr' (consoante + R) são
>   indivisíveis. Exemplos: ca-pri-no. ■ Possível encontro consonantal
>   perfeito 'pr' (também chamado de próprio, ou inseparável ou puro). Há
>   encontro consonantal perfeito quando, na divisão silábica, as
>   consoantes se mantêm inseparáveis, permanecendo dentro da mesma
>   sílaba. É o caso das consoantes "l" e "r" juntamente com outras
>   consoantes: dr, tr, gr, vr, cl, fl, pl, bl,… e os grupos consonantais
>   que aparecem no início das palavras. Exemplos: Bra-sil, a-tle-ta,
>   blu-sa, brin-co, cla-ro, cli-ma, dra-ma, es-cre-ve, flo-co, flo-res,
>   fra-co, fri-ta-dei-ra, gno-mo, gru-po, in-glês, li-vro, pa-la-vra,
>   pla-ca, pneu-má-ti-co, pra-te-lei-ra, pró-xi-mo, psi-có-lo-go, tri-go.

Polícia:

- po-lí-cia (no Brasil)
- po-lí-ci-a (no Portugal e restante CPLP)

> Quantas sílabas tem polícia? 3 sílabas (no Brasil), ou 4 sílabas (no
>   Portugal e restante CPLP). No Brasil é uma palavra grave ou também
>   chamado paroxítona (acento tônico na penúltima sílaba). No Portugal e
>   restante CPLP, é uma palavra proparoxítona (acento tónico na
>   antepenúltima sílaba). ■ Hiato i-a. Veja mais exemplos do palavras con
>   'ia'. ■ Exceções: Palavras terminadas em hiato 'i-a'; com a sílaba
>   anterior acentuada são indivisíveis. Exemplos: fa-mí-lia, pá-tria.
>   Veja mais exemplos do palavras con 'ia' ■ O Acordo Ortográfico Da
>   Língua Portuguesa (1990), Base VII, 2º-C, diz: Além dos ditongos orais
>   propriamente ditos, os quais são todos decrescentes, admite-se, como é
>   sabido, a existência de ditongos crescentes. Podem considerar-se no
>   número deles as sequências vocálicas pós-tónicas/pós-tônicas, tais as
>   que se representam graficamente por ea, eo, ia, ie, io, oa, ua, ue,
>   uo: áurea, áureo, calúnia, espécie, exímio, mágoa, míngua,
>   ténue/tênue, tríduo. ■ [i + vogal] Se a letra 'i' não acentuada for
>   seguida por outra vogal não acentuada este encontro vocálico pode ser
>   pronunciado de duas maneiras distintas:
>     1. Como ditongo crescente 'ia', 'ie', 'ii', 'io', 'iu', com a pronúncia das duas vogais em uma mesma sílaba e realização de 'i' como
>   semivogal. Exemplos: fé-rias, a-gên-cia.
>     2. Como hiato 'i-a', 'i-e', 'i-i', 'i-o', 'i-u', com a separação das duas vogais em duas sílabas distintas e a representação de 'i' como
>   vogal. Exemplos: fé-ri-as, a-gên-ci-a. A escolha da variante mais
>   adequada para estes casos é facultativa e poderá ser motivada por
>   razões de ordem técnica ou estética. ■ De acordo com o site
>   Wiktionary: A categoria de palavras proparoxítonas aparentes foi
>   criada no wikcionário para resolver o problema das palavras que são
>   classificadas segundo seu acento tônico de uma maneira no Brasil e de
>   outra em Portugal, especificamente aquelas que são acentuadas por
>   terminarem em um ditongo crescente (-ea, -eo, -ia, -ie, -io, -ua, -ue
>   e -uo), que são classificadas como paroxítonas terminadas em ditongo
>   no Brasil, mas como proparoxítonas no restante da CPLP. Exemplo:
>   Palavras como sério, bário, tília, são consideradas como dissílabas no
>   Brasil (suas divisões silábicas são respectivamente sé-rio, bá-rio,
>   tí-lia) mas são vistas como trissílabas em Portugal, onde suas
>   divisões silábicas seriam sé-ri-o, bá-ri-o, tí-li-a.

Óleo

- ó-leo (no Brasil)
- ó-le-o (no Portugal e restante CPLP)

> Quantas sílabas tem óleo? 2 sílabas (no Brasil), ou 3 sílabas (no
>   Portugal e restante CPLP). No Brasil é uma palavra grave ou também
>   chamado paroxítona (acento tônico na penúltima sílaba). No Portugal e
>   restante CPLP, é uma palavra proparoxítona (acento tónico na
>   antepenúltima sílaba). ■ Hiato e-o. Ficam abolidas as escritas ae, ao,
>   eo, oe, ue, para estes ditongos, quer em nomes, quer em formas verbais
>   (Veja 'XIII escrita de ditongos orais'). Veja mais exemplos do
>   palavras con 'eo'. ■ Exceções: Palavras terminadas em 'e-o'; com a
>   sílaba anterior acentuada são indivisíveis. Exemplos: cu-tâ-neo,
>   ins-tan-tâ-neo. Veja mais exemplos do palavras con 'eo' ■ O Acordo
>   Ortográfico Da Língua Portuguesa (1990), Base VII, 2º-C, diz: Além dos
>   ditongos orais propriamente ditos, os quais são todos decrescentes,
>   admite-se, como é sabido, a existência de ditongos crescentes. Podem
>   considerar-se no número deles as sequências vocálicas
>   pós-tónicas/pós-tônicas, tais as que se representam graficamente por
>   ea, eo, ia, ie, io, oa, ua, ue, uo: áurea, áureo, calúnia, espécie,
>   exímio, mágoa, míngua, ténue/tênue, tríduo. ■ De acordo com o site
>   Wiktionary: A categoria de palavras proparoxítonas aparentes foi
>   criada no wikcionário para resolver o problema das palavras que são
>   classificadas segundo seu acento tônico de uma maneira no Brasil e de
>   outra em Portugal, especificamente aquelas que são acentuadas por
>   terminarem em um ditongo crescente (-ea, -eo, -ia, -ie, -io, -ua, -ue
>   e -uo), que são classificadas como paroxítonas terminadas em ditongo
>   no Brasil, mas como proparoxítonas no restante da CPLP. Exemplo:
>   Palavras como sério, bário, tília, são consideradas como dissílabas no
>   Brasil (suas divisões silábicas são respectivamente sé-rio, bá-rio,
>   tí-lia) mas são vistas como trissílabas em Portugal, onde suas
>   divisões silábicas seriam sé-ri-o, bá-ri-o, tí-li-a.

Ministério:

- mi-nis-té-rio (no Brasil)
- mi-nis-té-ri-o (no Portugal e restante CPLP)

> Quantas sílabas tem ministério? 4 sílabas (no Brasil), ou 5 sílabas
>   (no Portugal e restante CPLP). No Brasil é uma palavra grave ou também
>   chamado paroxítona (acento tônico na penúltima sílaba). No Portugal e
>   restante CPLP, é uma palavra proparoxítona (acento tónico na
>   antepenúltima sílaba). ■ Hiato i-o. Veja mais exemplos do palavras con
>   'io'. ■ Exceções: Palavras terminadas em hiato 'i-o'; com a sílaba
>   anterior acentuada são indivisíveis. Exemplos: ar-má-rio, bal-dio,
>   ca-ná-rio, con-do-mí-nio, Má-rio. Veja mais exemplos do palavras con
>   'io' ■ O Acordo Ortográfico Da Língua Portuguesa (1990), Base VII,
>   2º-C, diz: Além dos ditongos orais propriamente ditos, os quais são
>   todos decrescentes, admite-se, como é sabido, a existência de ditongos
>   crescentes. Podem considerar-se no número deles as sequências
>   vocálicas pós-tónicas/pós-tônicas, tais as que se representam
>   graficamente por ea, eo, ia, ie, io, oa, ua, ue, uo: áurea, áureo,
>   calúnia, espécie, exímio, mágoa, míngua, ténue/tênue, tríduo. ■ [i +
>   vogal] Se a letra 'i' não acentuada for seguida por outra vogal não
>   acentuada este encontro vocálico pode ser pronunciado de duas maneiras
>   distintas:
>     1. Como ditongo crescente 'ia', 'ie', 'ii', 'io', 'iu', com a pronúncia das duas vogais em uma mesma sílaba e realização de 'i' como
>   semivogal. Exemplos: fé-rias, a-gên-cia.
>     2. Como hiato 'i-a', 'i-e', 'i-i', 'i-o', 'i-u', com a separação das duas vogais em duas sílabas distintas e a representação de 'i' como
>   vogal. Exemplos: fé-ri-as, a-gên-ci-a. A escolha da variante mais
>   adequada para estes casos é facultativa e poderá ser motivada por
>   razões de ordem técnica ou estética. ■ De acordo com o site
>   Wiktionary: A categoria de palavras proparoxítonas aparentes foi
>   criada no wikcionário para resolver o problema das palavras que são
>   classificadas segundo seu acento tônico de uma maneira no Brasil e de
>   outra em Portugal, especificamente aquelas que são acentuadas por
>   terminarem em um ditongo crescente (-ea, -eo, -ia, -ie, -io, -ua, -ue
>   e -uo), que são classificadas como paroxítonas terminadas em ditongo
>   no Brasil, mas como proparoxítonas no restante da CPLP. Exemplo:
>   Palavras como sério, bário, tília, são consideradas como dissílabas no
>   Brasil (suas divisões silábicas são respectivamente sé-rio, bá-rio,
>   tí-lia) mas são vistas como trissílabas em Portugal, onde suas
>   divisões silábicas seriam sé-ri-o, bá-ri-o, tí-li-a. ■ Possível
>   encontro consonantal imperfeito 'st' (também chamado de impróprio, ou
>   separável, ou disjunto). Há encontro consonantal imperfeito quando, na
>   divisão silábica, as consoantes se separam, ficando em sílabas
>   diferentes. Os mais comuns são formados pelos encontros bj, bs, ct,
>   dv, ft, gn, lm, ls, pt, rc, rt, st, tm... Exemplos: ab-sol-ver,
>   ad-vo-ga-do, af-ta, af-tas, al-mo-ço, ap-ti-dão, ar-co, as-pec-to,
>   bol-so, com-vul-são, cos-tas, dig-no, for-te, mag-né-ti-co,
>   ob-je-ti-vo, por-tão, rit-mo.

Answer (score 1):

A forma correcta é a primeira para todas as palavras.

- Pró-pri-a
- Po-lí-ci-a
- Ó-le-o
- Mi-nis-té-ri-o